# zsh key binding: cannot bind to an empty key sequence

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

The most recent update to zsh produced the following error on Mac OS X Maverick:
`/Users/[username]/.oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.zsh:bindkey:23: cannot bind to an empty key sequence`

The corresponding lines are:

```
bindkey "${terminfo[kpp]}" up-line-or-history       # [PageUp] - Up a line of history
bindkey "${terminfo[knp]}" down-line-or-history     # [PageDown] - Down a line of history
```

<del>There is no PageUp, PageDown, Home and End on the Mac keyboard.</del> I wonder why the correct key code is considered nil by bindkey or how the conditional should look like if ${terminfo[kpp]} is nil. Any ideas?

Comment: The error is a little odd, because whether or not your keyboard has the keys, the terminal should still have a key sequence it will recognize as page up or page down. (On a Macbook Pro, for example, fn-up-arrow sends the same key code as Page Up on a keyboard that has such a key.)

Comment: That's correct. Edited the post.

Comment: Does `print ${(k)terminfo}` produce any output? I would think that you would need to run `zmodload zsh/terminfo` to make the `terminfo` array available, although it doesn't seem to be necessary based on my `zsh` setup.

Comment: It sure does. But `kpp` is not part of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to do with $terminfo not being consistent across platforms, the commit has been reverted see https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2608 for details. If you got the hub tool installed the quick fix is:

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh 
hub checkout https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/2625 terminfo_fix
```

and reload your shell. Without hub you need to setup the remote for the PR first and pull from there.

Comment: terminfo key verification seems a little better to me than total reversion. I added another pull request 2634.